# Associate a keypress event with a event handler in a array of textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I've an array of `textboxes` that generates run-time a variable number of `textboxes` such the value of a `textbox` already created into the form.

```
 int n;
 TextBox[] tb;        

 public void AggiungiArmoniche()
 {
        n = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
        tb = new 
        TextBox[n];

    for (int i = 1; i < tb.Length; i++)
    {
        tb[i] = new TextBox();            
        tb[i].Name = "textBox" + i;                
        tb[i].Location = new Point(100 *i, 163);
        tb[i].Size = new Size(48, 20);
        tb[i].KeyPress += System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(textBoxP_KeyPress);            
        groupBox1.Controls.Add(tb[i]);            
    }
} 

private void textBoxP_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  // statements of the event        
}
```

When I move to the line in which i associate the event to the event-handler it gives the error *it isn't a valid construct in the contest" (in particular in the word `keypresseventhandler`)*

is there a syntactical error in the association?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new

```
tb[i].KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(textBoxP_KeyPress);
```

Comment: thank you very much user959729..i have not noticed that absented that word.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the KeyPressEventHandler and add the event handler like so

```
tb[i].KeyPress += textBoxP_KeyPress;
```